# Fast/parallel alternative to GLS with nlme?

Tags: r, spatial, model-evaluation, parallel-computing, generalized-least-squares

I am using the gls function from nlme to fit a fixed-effects model yet correct for spatial autocorrelation. My dataset has about 100,000 unique geographic observations, and running the following functions takes days on a R 64-bit edition installed on a quad-core Intel i7 3.4GHz CPU:

```
fit <- gls(frm, data, correlation = corSpher(form=~longitude+latitude,nugget=TRUE))
```

I tried the same on a Linux machine with 16 AMD Opteron processors, and it takes even longer.
Is there any R package out there that will do the same job in a more efficient or parallel way?

Comment: Hmm... Nothing spring immediately into mind but maybe you can base something of your own using `fastLm()` from RcppEigen to speed things up. Also maybe something based on online regression be an option.

Comment: You might need to guestimate the parameters for the spherical spatial process. That model is trying to solve parameters for the spatial process and for the main effects all at the same time. IIRC that will involve inversion of some big matrices which is where the computations get bogged down. I've had the same trouble with huge time series.

Comment: And by guestimate I mean fit the model without the correlation term, fit the spherical model to the residuals, get those parameters and then refit with `gls()` but state the parameter values rather than use the formula using argument `value`. Without the nugget you'd only need to specify the range as a parameter but with the nugget you will need both the range and `1 - cor(i,j)` when `i` and `j` are two observations close together in space. See `?corSpher` for details. You don't even need to fit the model without the correlation structure if you can have reasonable guesses at those parameters.

Comment: Thanks @GavinSimpson! I have tried your approach and eventually decided to move to GAM, that appears more flexible and efficient.